# Rotating a bolt around the centre

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bolting

I have a setup in which a bolt threaded on two ends with an unthreaded shank in the middle will be rotated by the unthreaded shank area. That is, the bolt's axis of rotation is roughly the red cross:

[image]

I wonder if there's a small part/connector that I could fit over the unthreaded shank so that a shaft could be connected to the connector such that the bolt can be rotated. Perhaps, something like below where the top is a hex/square hole and the bottom is a threaded hole?

[image]

Alternatively, are there low-profile setups where a bolt can be rotated around the centre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clamp collars can attach to the bolt and shank:
http://www.mcmaster.com/#shaft-collars/=10hrt5k

Holes can be tapped in the sides of the clamp collars and then can be bolted together by making a bracket as needed.

Clamping handers are also sold that bolt together, but these are in limited sizes: http://www.mcmaster.com/#routing-collars/=10hrtms

Answer (score 0):

depends on the application but a TCB Stud may be a possibility - this has a left hand thread on the end opposite the spline and a right hand thread on the end nearest the spline.  The left hand thread is tightened by the installation tool into a left-handed threaded nut and then the right hand threaded nut is tightened against the washer against the steel.